# How to validate URIs by checking if those refer to a given domain name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, uri

I am running Ruby on Rails 4.1.1 and I would like to validate URIs by checking if those are within a given domain name. That is, a `uri` string can be sent as `params` to my controller and I would like to check if that `uri` "refers" to my application domain name `www.myapp.com`. Of course, the `uri` should be a valid [URI reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier#URI_reference).

```
# Invalid URIs
www.website.com
http://www.website.com
http://www.website.com/
https://www.website.com/
ftp://www.website.com/
ftps://www.website.com/
http://www.website.com/some/path

# Valid URIs
www.myapp.com
http://www.myapp.com
http://www.myapp.com/
https://www.myapp.com/
ftp://www.myapp.com/
ftps://www.myapp.com/
http://www.myapp.com/some/path
```

How can I make that (maybe by using just Ruby on Rails)?

Note: I am validating URIs in order to allow users to set custom redirects and I am aware of [vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet). I plan to run validations in a method stated in my `application_controller.rb`.

Comment: Use this - http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse 'http://www.website.com/some/path'

isOK = case uri.host
       when 'www.website.com' then true
       else false
       end

#⇒ true
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Currently [Addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) is my preferred choice for working with URIs:

```
require 'addressable/uri'

Addressable::URI.parse('http://www.myapp.com/some/path').host == 'www.myapp.com'
```