# Clarifications about OWASP documentation for user redirection by using parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, ruby-on-rails-4, owasp

I am using Ruby on Rails 4.1.1 and I would like to accept a `redirect_path` parameter in order to redirect users after they have performed an action. I read the [OWASP documentation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Ruby_on_Rails_Cheatsheet#Redirects_and_Forwards) about related concerns (phishing attacks) but I did not understand something. The documentation states:

> The most basic, but restrictive protection is to use the :only_path
>   option. Setting this to true will essentially strip out any host
>   information.

```
redirect_to params[:url], :only_path => true
```

Is the `redirect_to params[:url], :only_path => true` enough in order to avoid phishing attacks? There may be other pitfalls?

Comment: The OWASP page is actually wrong. Please read http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/redirect/ for updated suggestions (or use Frank's other code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Brakeman](http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/redirect/) suggests two strategies to mitigate the risks:

1. Using `only_path` as you did;
2. Parsing the redirect URL to extract the path manually `URI.parse(some_url).path`

In past projects I've rewrote that helper to be sure nobody would accidentally forget the extra param of #1.

Comment: Can you provide some example code on how you'd handle the issue by adopting solution #1 and #2?

Comment: 1. `redirect_to your_options_hash.merge(only_path: true)`

2. `redirect_to URI.parse(some_url).path`

Was this what you expected?

Comment: I am asking for! Example: 1. [Is it safe to accept URL parameters for populating the `url_for` method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324563/is-it-safe-to-accept-url-parameters-for-populating-the-url-for-method);  2. [How to validate URIs by checking if those refer to a given domain name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27859332/how-to-validate-uris-by-checking-if-those-refer-to-a-given-domain-name).

Comment: Ok. So for 1/ my understanding is that is is safe as long as you ensure you're only passing paths (or trusted URLs). As for 2/ that's an issue I would like to adress in ActiveValidatord (https://github.com/franckverrot/activevalidators/issues/59), once it's resolved in AV, it would be easy to wrap this up in a class an use only that class for redirects.